# RelativeLayout with Scrollview in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio

I know this is common to ask but I'm confused. I have a `RelativeLayout` forms with `editText` and `spinner`, now I want to apply the `ScrollView` to scroll the data from above to bottom since I have a lot of data to be inputted. I tried putting `Scrollview` after the first layout but it doesn't work. Need help

[image]

**Activitymain.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="@color/background"
tools:context=".SignUp">


<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/linear2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/confirmRequestBtn"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/selector_fieldset_background">

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/til_Idno"
        app:counterEnabled="true"
        app:counterMaxLength="23"
        app:endIconMode="clear_text"
        app:helperText="Good valid!"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        app:helperTextTextColor="@color/validation"
        app:startIconDrawable="@drawable/ic_creditcard"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox.Dense">

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:maxLength="23"
            android:hint="ID No."
            android:id="@+id/edtIdno"
            android:inputType="number"/>
    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/til_patientType"

        app:helperText="Mandatory"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        app:helperTextTextColor="@color/validation"
        android:layout_below="@+id/til_Idno"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox.Dense">

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinnerAppointmentCat"
            android:layout_width= "match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/edtIdno"/>
    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/til_complaints"
        app:helperText="Mandatory"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        app:helperTextTextColor="@color/validation"
        android:layout_below="@+id/til_patientType"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox.Dense">

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinnerComplaints"
            android:layout_width= "match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/spinnerAppointmentCat"/>


    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/til_firstname"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:endIconMode="clear_text"
        app:helperText="Mandatory"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        app:helperTextTextColor="@color/validation"
        app:startIconDrawable="@drawable/ic_series"
        android:layout_below="@+id/til_complaints"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox.Dense">

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="First name"
            android:id="@+id/edtFirstname"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:layout_below="@id/spinnerComplaints"/>
    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/til_middlename"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:endIconMode="clear_text"
        app:helperText="Mandatory"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        app:helperTextTextColor="@color/validation"
        app:startIconDrawable="@drawable/ic_series"
        android:layout_below="@+id/til_firstname"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox.Dense">

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Middle name/initial"
            android:id="@+id/edtMiddleName"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:layout_below="@id/edtFirstname"/>
    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/til_lastname"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:endIconMode="clear_text"
        app:helperText="Mandatory"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        app:helperTextTextColor="@color/validation"
        app:startIconDrawable="@drawable/ic_series"
        android:layout_below="@+id/til_middlename"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox.Dense">

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Middle name/initial"
            android:id="@+id/edtLastname"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:layout_below="@id/edtMiddleName"/>
    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/til_sex"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:endIconMode="clear_text"
        app:helperText="Mandatory"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        app:helperTextTextColor="@color/validation"
        app:startIconDrawable="@drawable/ic_series"
        android:layout_below="@+id/til_lastname"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox.Dense">

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Sex"
            android:id="@+id/edtSex"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:layout_below="@id/edtLastname"/>
    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/til_birthdate"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:endIconMode="clear_text"
        app:helperText="Mandatory"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        app:helperTextTextColor="@color/validation"
        app:startIconDrawable="@drawable/ic_series"
        android:layout_below="@+id/til_sex"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox.Dense">

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Sex"
            android:id="@+id/edtBirthdate"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:layout_below="@id/edtSex"/>
    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/til_cpno"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:endIconMode="clear_text"
        app:helperText="Mandatory"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        app:helperTextTextColor="@color/validation"
        app:startIconDrawable="@drawable/ic_series"
        android:layout_below="@+id/til_birthdate"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox.Dense">

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Contact"
            android:id="@+id/edtContact"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:layout_below="@id/edtBirthdate"/>
    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/til_email"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:endIconMode="clear_text"
        app:helperText="Mandatory"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        app:helperTextTextColor="@color/validation"
        app:startIconDrawable="@drawable/ic_series"
        android:layout_below="@+id/til_birthdate"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox.Dense">

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Email"
            android:id="@+id/edtEmail"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:layout_below="@id/edtContact"/>
    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/til_address"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:endIconMode="clear_text"
        app:helperText="Mandatory"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        app:helperTextTextColor="@color/validation"
        app:startIconDrawable="@drawable/ic_series"
        android:layout_below="@+id/til_email"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox.Dense">

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Address"
            android:id="@+id/edtAddress"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:layout_below="@id/edtEmail"/>
    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>



</RelativeLayout>
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/background"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:text="Appointment"
    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:textSize="15dp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/confirmRequestBtn"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:background="@drawable/mybutton"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:text="Confirm Request"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"/>
```

**UPDATED : This is what I've tried** I put `ScrollView` after the second `RelativeLayout` but where should I put the close tag of `ScrollView` and `LinearLayout` it brokes the design If I put it before `RelativeLayout`

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="@color/background"
tools:context=".SignUp">


<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/linear2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/confirmRequestBtn"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/selector_fieldset_background">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/til_Idno"
        app:counterEnabled="true"
        app:counterMaxLength="23"
        app:endIconMode="clear_text"
        app:helperText="Good valid!"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        app:helperTextTextColor="@color/validation"
        app:startIconDrawable="@drawable/ic_creditcard"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox.Dense">

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:maxLength="23"
            android:hint="ID No."
            android:id="@+id/edtIdno"
            android:inputType="number"/>
    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/til_patientType"

        app:helperText="Mandatory"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        app:helperTextTextColor="@color/validation"
        android:layout_below="@+id/til_Idno"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox.Dense">

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinnerAppointmentCat"
            android:layout_width= "match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/edtIdno"/>
    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/til_complaints"
        app:helperText="Mandatory"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        app:helperTextTextColor="@color/validation"
        android:layout_below="@+id/til_patientType"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox.Dense">

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinnerComplaints"
            android:layout_width= "match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/spinnerAppointmentCat"/>


    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/til_firstname"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:endIconMode="clear_text"
        app:helperText="Mandatory"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        app:helperTextTextColor="@color/validation"
        app:startIconDrawable="@drawable/ic_series"
        android:layout_below="@+id/til_complaints"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox.Dense">

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="First name"
            android:id="@+id/edtFirstname"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:layout_below="@id/spinnerComplaints"/>
    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/til_middlename"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:endIconMode="clear_text"
        app:helperText="Mandatory"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        app:helperTextTextColor="@color/validation"
        app:startIconDrawable="@drawable/ic_series"
        android:layout_below="@+id/til_firstname"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox.Dense">

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Middle name/initial"
            android:id="@+id/edtMiddleName"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:layout_below="@id/edtFirstname"/>
    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/til_lastname"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:endIconMode="clear_text"
        app:helperText="Mandatory"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        app:helperTextTextColor="@color/validation"
        app:startIconDrawable="@drawable/ic_series"
        android:layout_below="@+id/til_middlename"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox.Dense">

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Middle name/initial"
            android:id="@+id/edtLastname"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:layout_below="@id/edtMiddleName"/>
    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/til_sex"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:endIconMode="clear_text"
        app:helperText="Mandatory"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        app:helperTextTextColor="@color/validation"
        app:startIconDrawable="@drawable/ic_series"
        android:layout_below="@+id/til_lastname"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox.Dense">

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Sex"
            android:id="@+id/edtSex"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:layout_below="@id/edtLastname"/>
    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/til_birthdate"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:endIconMode="clear_text"
        app:helperText="Mandatory"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        app:helperTextTextColor="@color/validation"
        app:startIconDrawable="@drawable/ic_series"
        android:layout_below="@+id/til_sex"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox.Dense">

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Sex"
            android:id="@+id/edtBirthdate"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:layout_below="@id/edtSex"/>
    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/til_cpno"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:endIconMode="clear_text"
        app:helperText="Mandatory"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        app:helperTextTextColor="@color/validation"
        app:startIconDrawable="@drawable/ic_series"
        android:layout_below="@+id/til_birthdate"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox.Dense">

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Contact"
            android:id="@+id/edtContact"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:layout_below="@id/edtBirthdate"/>
    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/til_email"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:endIconMode="clear_text"
        app:helperText="Mandatory"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        app:helperTextTextColor="@color/validation"
        app:startIconDrawable="@drawable/ic_series"
        android:layout_below="@+id/til_birthdate"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox.Dense">

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Email"
            android:id="@+id/edtEmail"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:layout_below="@id/edtContact"/>
    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/til_address"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:endIconMode="clear_text"
        app:helperText="Mandatory"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        app:helperTextTextColor="@color/validation"
        app:startIconDrawable="@drawable/ic_series"
        android:layout_below="@+id/til_email"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox.Dense">

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Address"
            android:id="@+id/edtAddress"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:layout_below="@id/edtEmail"/>
    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>



</RelativeLayout>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/background"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:text="Appointment"
    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:textSize="15dp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/confirmRequestBtn"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:background="@drawable/mybutton"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:text="Confirm Request"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: do you want to apply scrollview to full view??

Comment: @Tanishq Chawda Yes

Answer (score 1):

your ScrollView should contain a layout inside it :

**EDIT**
the attribut `android:orientation` in your `LinearLayout` should be `vertical` instead of `horizontal`

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="Vertical">
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/til_Idno"
    app:counterEnabled="true"
    app:counterMaxLength="23"
    app:endIconMode="clear_text"
    app:helperText="Good valid!"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    app:helperTextTextColor="@color/validation"
    app:startIconDrawable="@drawable/ic_creditcard"
    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox.Dense">

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:maxLength="23"
        android:hint="ID No."
        android:id="@+id/edtIdno"
        android:inputType="number"/>
</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/til_patientType"

    app:helperText="Mandatory"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    app:helperTextTextColor="@color/validation"
    android:layout_below="@+id/til_Idno"
    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox.Dense">

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinnerAppointmentCat"
        android:layout_width= "match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/edtIdno"/>
</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/til_complaints"
    app:helperText="Mandatory"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    app:helperTextTextColor="@color/validation"
    android:layout_below="@+id/til_patientType"
    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox.Dense">

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinnerComplaints"
        android:layout_width= "match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/spinnerAppointmentCat"/>


</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/til_firstname"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:endIconMode="clear_text"
    app:helperText="Mandatory"
    android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    app:helperTextTextColor="@color/validation"
    app:startIconDrawable="@drawable/ic_series"
    android:layout_below="@+id/til_complaints"
    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox.Dense">

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="First name"
        android:id="@+id/edtFirstname"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:layout_below="@id/spinnerComplaints"/>
</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/til_middlename"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:endIconMode="clear_text"
    app:helperText="Mandatory"
    android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    app:helperTextTextColor="@color/validation"
    app:startIconDrawable="@drawable/ic_series"
    android:layout_below="@+id/til_firstname"
    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox.Dense">

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Middle name/initial"
        android:id="@+id/edtMiddleName"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:layout_below="@id/edtFirstname"/>
</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/til_lastname"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:endIconMode="clear_text"
    app:helperText="Mandatory"
    android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    app:helperTextTextColor="@color/validation"
    app:startIconDrawable="@drawable/ic_series"
    android:layout_below="@+id/til_middlename"
    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox.Dense">

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Middle name/initial"
        android:id="@+id/edtLastname"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:layout_below="@id/edtMiddleName"/>
</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/til_sex"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:endIconMode="clear_text"
    app:helperText="Mandatory"
    android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    app:helperTextTextColor="@color/validation"
    app:startIconDrawable="@drawable/ic_series"
    android:layout_below="@+id/til_lastname"
    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox.Dense">

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Sex"
        android:id="@+id/edtSex"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:layout_below="@id/edtLastname"/>
</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/til_birthdate"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:endIconMode="clear_text"
    app:helperText="Mandatory"
    android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    app:helperTextTextColor="@color/validation"
    app:startIconDrawable="@drawable/ic_series"
    android:layout_below="@+id/til_sex"
    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox.Dense">

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Sex"
        android:id="@+id/edtBirthdate"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:layout_below="@id/edtSex"/>
</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/til_cpno"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:endIconMode="clear_text"
    app:helperText="Mandatory"
    android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    app:helperTextTextColor="@color/validation"
    app:startIconDrawable="@drawable/ic_series"
    android:layout_below="@+id/til_birthdate"
    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox.Dense">

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Contact"
        android:id="@+id/edtContact"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:layout_below="@id/edtBirthdate"/>
  </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

  <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/til_email"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:endIconMode="clear_text"
    app:helperText="Mandatory"
    android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    app:helperTextTextColor="@color/validation"
    app:startIconDrawable="@drawable/ic_series"
    android:layout_below="@+id/til_birthdate"
    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox.Dense">

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Email"
        android:id="@+id/edtEmail"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:layout_below="@id/edtContact"/>
  </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

  <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/til_address"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:endIconMode="clear_text"
    app:helperText="Mandatory"
    android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    app:helperTextTextColor="@color/validation"
    app:startIconDrawable="@drawable/ic_series"
    android:layout_below="@+id/til_email"
    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox.Dense">

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Address"
        android:id="@+id/edtAddress"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:layout_below="@id/edtEmail"/>
</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

Comment: But where should I close the tag that you given which is `ScrollView` and `LinearLayout`  I tried putting the close tag before `RelativeLayout but it seems it brokes the design of the layout

Comment: I have updated my code above and Applied you've given above but where should I out the close tag of `ScrollView` and `LinearLayout` that you've been created??

Comment: you have to close the `LinearLayout` tag after your last `TextInputLayout` tag, then close `ScrollView` tag

Comment: check my edited answer, please.

Answer (score 0):

You must check whether it's like that or not...have a look into it.

```
    <RelativeLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="@color/background"
        tools:context=".SignUp">
    
          
        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/linear2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_above="@+id/confirmRequestBtn"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:background="@drawable/selector_fieldset_background">
            <ScrollView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:fillViewport="true">
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">
           <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/til_Idno"
            app:counterEnabled="true"
            app:counterMaxLength="23"
            app:endIconMode="clear_text"
            app:helperText="Good valid!"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            app:helperTextTextColor="@color/validation"
            app:startIconDrawable="@drawable/ic_creditcard"
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox.Dense">
    
            <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:maxLength="23"
                android:hint="ID No."
                android:id="@+id/edtIdno"
                android:inputType="number"/>
        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/til_patientType"
    
            app:helperText="Mandatory"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            app:helperTextTextColor="@color/validation"
            android:layout_below="@+id/til_Idno"
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox.Dense">
    
            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/spinnerAppointmentCat"
                android:layout_width= "match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/edtIdno"/>
        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/til_complaints"
            app:helperText="Mandatory"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            app:helperTextTextColor="@color/validation"
            android:layout_below="@+id/til_patientType"
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox.Dense">
    
            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/spinnerComplaints"
                android:layout_width= "match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/spinnerAppointmentCat"/>
    
    
        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
    
        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/til_firstname"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:endIconMode="clear_text"
            app:helperText="Mandatory"
            android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            app:helperTextTextColor="@color/validation"
            app:startIconDrawable="@drawable/ic_series"
            android:layout_below="@+id/til_complaints"
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox.Dense">
    
            <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="First name"
                android:id="@+id/edtFirstname"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:layout_below="@id/spinnerComplaints"/>
        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
    
        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/til_middlename"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:endIconMode="clear_text"
            app:helperText="Mandatory"
            android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            app:helperTextTextColor="@color/validation"
            app:startIconDrawable="@drawable/ic_series"
            android:layout_below="@+id/til_firstname"
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox.Dense">
    
            <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="Middle name/initial"
                android:id="@+id/edtMiddleName"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:layout_below="@id/edtFirstname"/>
        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/til_lastname"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:endIconMode="clear_text"
            app:helperText="Mandatory"
            android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            app:helperTextTextColor="@color/validation"
            app:startIconDrawable="@drawable/ic_series"
            android:layout_below="@+id/til_middlename"
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox.Dense">
    
            <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="Middle name/initial"
                android:id="@+id/edtLastname"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:layout_below="@id/edtMiddleName"/>
        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
    
        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/til_sex"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:endIconMode="clear_text"
            app:helperText="Mandatory"
            android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            app:helperTextTextColor="@color/validation"
            app:startIconDrawable="@drawable/ic_series"
            android:layout_below="@+id/til_lastname"
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox.Dense">
    
            <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="Sex"
                android:id="@+id/edtSex"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:layout_below="@id/edtLastname"/>
        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/til_birthdate"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:endIconMode="clear_text"
            app:helperText="Mandatory"
            android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            app:helperTextTextColor="@color/validation"
            app:startIconDrawable="@drawable/ic_series"
            android:layout_below="@+id/til_sex"
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox.Dense">
    
            <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="Sex"
                android:id="@+id/edtBirthdate"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:layout_below="@id/edtSex"/>
        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/til_cpno"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:endIconMode="clear_text"
            app:helperText="Mandatory"
            android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            app:helperTextTextColor="@color/validation"
            app:startIconDrawable="@drawable/ic_series"
            android:layout_below="@+id/til_birthdate"
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox.Dense">
    
            <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="Contact"
                android:id="@+id/edtContact"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:layout_below="@id/edtBirthdate"/>
        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
         <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/til_email"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:endIconMode="clear_text"
            app:helperText="Mandatory"
            android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            app:helperTextTextColor="@color/validation"
            app:startIconDrawable="@drawable/ic_series"
            android:layout_below="@+id/til_birthdate"
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox.Dense">
    
            <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="Email"
                android:id="@+id/edtEmail"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:layout_below="@id/edtContact"/>
        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
    
        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/til_address"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:endIconMode="clear_text"
            app:helperText="Mandatory"
            android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            app:helperTextTextColor="@color/validation"
            app:startIconDrawable="@drawable/ic_series"
            android:layout_below="@+id/til_email"
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox.Dense">
    
            <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="Address"
                android:id="@+id/edtAddress"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:layout_below="@id/edtEmail"/>
        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
        </ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/background"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:text="Appointment"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textSize="15dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/confirmRequestBtn"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/mybutton"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:text="Confirm Request"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```